# The Stratonovich Integral and its meaning as the limit in mean square of a sum?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am studying the Stratonovich Integral and on wikipedia, [Stratonovich Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratonovich_integral), it states that the integral, for a process $X:[0,T] \times\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, as:

$$
\int_0^T X_t \circ dW_t
$$

is defined as the limit in mean square of:

$$
\sum_{i = 0}^{k - 1} {X_{t_{i+1}} + X_{t_i}\over 2} \left( W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i} \right)
$$

What I don't understand is what is the meaning of "limit in mean square". From what I understand, we have that:

$$
lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{i = 0}^{k - 1} {X_{t_{i+1}} + X_{t_i}\over 2} \left( W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i} \right) = \int_0^T X_t \circ dW_t
$$

Isn't this just the simple limit? Where is the mean square part come in, which by definition should have an expectation somewhere? I'd appreciate any insights, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It means that 
$$
lim_{k \to \infty}\Bbb E\left\{\left[\sum_{i = 0}^{k - 1} {X_{t_{i+1}} + X_{t_i}\over 2} \left( W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i} \right) - \int_0^T X_t \circ dW_t\right]^2\right\}=0.
$$

Comment: It should also be mentioned that the a.s. limit in general doesn't exist.

Comment: @Ian It is not clear to me why the a.s. limit doesn't exist. Is there a trivial proof of this? Thanks